# DataSet.ReadXml - Duplicate element names on different nest levels

Tags: .net, xml, dataset

Our code uses the DataSet::ReadXml method to convert our XML files to a DataSet. There seems to be a problem when elements at different nest levels have the same name.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Something>
    <MyValue>100</MyValue>
</Something>
```

This produces the follow datatable:

[image]

However, if the XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Something>
    <Something>100</MyValue>
</Something>
```

Then this produces the following datatable:

[image]

Unfortunately, we don't generate the XML files, so can't change this format without performing a pre-processing step on the XML file. Are there any alternative options for creating a DataSet from an XML file that doesn't display this issue?

Comment: you are probably getting 2 tables inside the dataset that represent hierarchy. Look for the other table

Comment: No, the dropdown in each screenshot only has the selected item in it.